# enable/disable textbox on click/unclick of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a  radio button named "CUSTOM". Upon clicking this radio button, I'd like the 2 textboxes next to it to change from "readonly to editable & then the date format of "yyyy/mm/dd" to be displayed inside the textboxes. I'm trying to achieve this by calling a function eb_tb &. Upn clicking any other radio button other than "CUSTOM", I'd like the textboxes to clear up & go readonly which I'm trying to do with dib_tb function. Neither of these seem to work unfortunately.

thisFile.php refers to the filename that the current code resides in. I'm referring to the same file to load the div which is hidden when the page loads.

Here's my code. Could someone please help me spot my mistake?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/revised.css"-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function setDivProps() {
            $('#resultblock').height(594).css({
               cursor: "auto",
               backgroundColor: "#A69A74",
              // backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
               marginLeft: "5%",
               marginTop: "5%",
               width: "88%",
               height: "75%",
               borderRadius: "25px",
               border: "2px solid black",
              // background: "url(image/divpic.jpg)" 
            });
         };

        function radio_check_enable_custom_date_range_text_box() {
            if (document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked) {
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').removeAttribute('readonly');
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').removeAttribute('readonly');
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
            }
        }
        ;


        function radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box() {
            document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked == false;
            if (document.getElementById('hd_radio_1').checked === false) {
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').value = '';
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').value = '';
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_1').setAttribute('readonly', true);
                document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id_2').setAttribute('readonly', true);
            }
        }
        ;

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cssmenu li').click(function(){
               $("#cssmenu li").removeClass("active");
               $(this).addClass("active");
             });

            $("#page1").click(function(){
               setDivProps();
               // $(this).css("background-color","black");
               $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_1');
            });

            $("#page2").click(function(){
               setDivProps();
               $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_2');
            });

            $("#page3").click(function(){
               setDivProps();
               $('#resultblock').load('thisFile.php #form_3');
            });
         });
   </script>
      <title>DEMO</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <header class="site-header-wrap">
            <div class="site-header">
               <h1>MY DEMO</h1>
            </div>
         </header>
         <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul class="uinav">
               <li class='active'><a id="home1" href='#' ><span>OPTION-1</span></a></li>
               <li><a id="page1" href="#"><span>OPTION-2</span></a></li>
               <li><a id="page2" href="#"><span>TOPTION-3</span></a></li>
               <li><a id="page3" href="#"><span>OPTION-4</span></a></li>  
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="div_id_1" style="display: none;">
            <form method="post" action="" id='form_1'>
              <table id="tbl_format_1">
                  <tr bgcolor="#8F4A11">
                      <td colspan="3" id="table_f_1">
                          <b> TIMELINE </b>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td colspan=3>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd1" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'week' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> WEEK </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd2" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'fortnight' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> FORTNIGHT </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd3" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> MONTH </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd4" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'three_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 1 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd5" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'six_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 2 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd6" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'nine_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 3 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd7" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'year' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> YEAR </INPUT>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr><td></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" Name ='bubble1'  value='custom' id="hd_radio_1" onclick="radio_check_enable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> CUSTOM &nbsp &nbsp => &nbsp &nbsp START DATE </INPUT>
                          &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="custom_date_range_id_1" readonly> </textarea> &nbsp &nbsp END DATE
                          &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="custom_date_range_id_2" readonly> </textarea>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="resultblock"> </div>
   </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the different ways I managed to work out this.

**SOLUTION - 1**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1600445.aspx?To+Hide+multiple+items+having+same+ID+using+Javascript

```
function hideAll(ctrlId)
{
    var Ctrls = document.all(ctrlId);
    for (var i = 0; i<Ctrls.items.length; i++)
    {
          var Ctrl = Ctrls.items(i);
          Ctrl.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION - 2**

Hiding elements with a specified id

UPDATE:

Well, if you need to hide a set of divs I usually add at all of them a class like .element-to-hide:

```
<div id="asd" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="lol" class="element-to-hide">...
<div id="foo" class="element-to-hide">...
Ant after just a touch of jQuery:

$('.element-to-hide').each(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

**SOLUTION -3**

I used this approach as I learned that creation of duplicate IDs on the same page isn't a good idea.

Instead of using the "hidden div approach", I moved the contents of the hidden div to a new PHP file. This way, when I load the contents via

**Contents of testhiddenblockconts.php**

```
<div id="div_id_1" style="display: none;">
                <form method="post" action="" id='form_1'>
                  <table id="tbl_format_1">
                      <tr bgcolor="#8F4A11">
                          <td colspan="3" id="table_f_1">
                              <b> TIMELINE </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan=3>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd1" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'week' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> WEEK </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd2" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'fortnight' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> FORTNIGHT </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd3" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> MONTH </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd4" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'three_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 1 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd5" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'six_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 2 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd6" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'nine_month' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> 3 - QUARTER </INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd7" Name ='bubble1'  value= 'year' onclick="radio_check_disable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> YEAR </INPUT>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><td></td></tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" Name ='bubble1'  value='custom' id="hd_radio_1" onclick="radio_check_enable_custom_date_range_text_box()"> CUSTOM &nbsp &nbsp => &nbsp &nbsp START DATE </INPUT>
                              &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="custom_date_range_id_1" readonly> </textarea> &nbsp &nbsp END DATE
                              &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="custom_date_range_id_2" readonly> </textarea>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </form>
             </div>
```

**The code in "thisFile.php" now looks as below**

```
$("#page1").click(function(){
                   setDivProps();
                   // $(this).css("background-color","black");
                   $('#resultblock').load('testhiddenblockconts.php #form_1');
                });
```

Hope this helps others in the same situation as I was in.

Answer (score 2):

On click of other radios you have to uncheck `#radio1` Here try this snippet
added `document.getElementById('radio_1').checked = false;` in function `dib_tb()`

```html
<html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/revised.css"-->
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myCustom.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             function setDivProps() {
                $('#resultblock').height(300).css({
                   cursor: "auto",
                  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                   marginLeft: "5%",
                   marginTop: "5%",
                   width: "90%",
                   height: "90%",
                   borderRadius: "2px",
                   border: "2px solid black",
                });
             };

            function eb_tb() {
                if (document.getElementById('radio_1').checked === true) {
                    document.getElementById('cdr1').removeAttribute('readonly');
                    document.getElementById('cdr2').removeAttribute('readonly');
                    document.getElementById('cdr1').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
                    document.getElementById('cdr2').value = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
                }
            }
            ;


            function dib_tb() {
    document.getElementById('radio_1').checked = false;
                if (document.getElementById('radio_1').checked === false) {
                    document.getElementById('cdr1').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('cdr2').value = '';
                    //document.getElementById('custom_date_range_id').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('cdr1').setAttribute('readonly', true);
                    document.getElementById('cdr2').setAttribute('readonly', true);
                }
            }
            ;

             $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#cssmenu li').click(function(){
                   $("#cssmenu li").removeClass("active");
                   $(this).addClass("active");
                 });

                $("#page1").click(function(){
                   setDivProps();
                   // $(this).css("background-color","black");
                   $('#resultblock').load('thisPage.php #form_id_1');
                });
             });
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div>
             <header class="site-header-wrap">
                <div class="site-header">
                   <h1>DEMO</h1>
                </div>
             </header>
             <div id='cssStyle'>
                <ul>
                   <li><a id="page1" href="#"><span>B</span></a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div style="">
                <form method="post" action="" id='form_id_1'>
                  <table >
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <b>TIMELINE </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan=4>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd1" Name ='optname1'  value= 'opt1' onclick="dib_tb()"> Option-1</INPUT>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" id="rd2" Name ='optname2'  value= 'opt2' onclick="dib_tb()"> Option-2</INPUT>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' class="radio_btn" Name ='radio_1_class1'  value= 'custom' id="radio_1" onclick="eb_tb()"> CUSTOM => START </INPUT>
                              &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="cdr1" readonly> </textarea> END
                              &nbsp &nbsp<textarea class="text_box" id="cdr2" readonly> </textarea>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </form>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id="resultblock"> </div>
       </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Hello Joy - Thank you for trying out. If the div is not hidden, the code does work. I have problem with that. In your answer, you've changed  <div style="display: none;"> to  <div style="">. My challenge lies in being able to get thmy code to work with a hidden div. Upon clicking a "li", I load the hidden div into a new div called "resultblock". I've just figured out that, that the eb_tb & dib_tb functions aren't able to find the elements by the "id" defined in the hidden div section. My guess is upon loading them to a new div, their ID changes. Could you please help me ?

Comment: OK the second one is your php file. Can you update your php file in here

Comment: I've updated the question with the latest code I'm fiddling with. Please save the full code as "thisFile.php" & launch in browser. I'm making a  call to the same file as the one that is loaded as the "div" section is in the same page. ANy help would really benefit me please.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this :

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#cdr1').hide();
           $('#cdr1').hide();
           $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
           if($(this).attr("value")=="opt1"){
              $('#cdr1').show();
              $('#cdr2').hide();

           }else if($(this).attr("value")=="opt2"){

             $('#cdr2').show();
              $('#cdr1').hide();
              }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Aich. I'll use this approach elsewhere. Thank you ehaps